# How to save matrices in an array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I was wondering is it possible in C language to save couple of matrices in an array and how to do that? Like, I pass a static matrix to a function and in a several steps I use the same matrix for different calculations, so I need to save every matrix with different result somewhere, so is it possible to save matrix as element of an array?

Comment: Without knowing how you represent your matrix in C, I cannot tell you how to save a copy of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so is it possible to save matrix as element of an array?

Yes, you can use a three dimensional array to store it's elements as matrices. Something like `array[no_of_matrices][row_no][column_no]` would do fine

example:

```
int arr[2][2][2];
// this would store 2 matrices of dimensions 2*2
```

Additionally, if you want arrays of different dimensions then you can create `**array[no_of_matrices]` and use **dynamic memory allocation** to allocate memory according to required dimensions of each matrix.